# Tranforming an ODE for $R(r)$ to a Bessel Equation of Order $m$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

> I have the ODE $$\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dR}{dr}\right)+\left(k^2 r-\frac{m^2}{r}\right)R=0.$$
>   I am trying to transform this ODE into the following Bessel equation of order $m$, $$p\frac{d}{dp}\left(p\frac{dR}{dp}\right)+(p^2-m^2)R=0.$$

It was suggested to me to use the substitution $p=kr$. Then $$\frac{dR}{dr}=\frac{dR}{dp}\frac{dp}{dr}=k\frac{dR}{dp}.$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\frac{p}{k}}\left(p\frac{dR}{dp}\right)+\left(kp-k\frac{m^2}{p}\right)R=0.
\end{align}
I do not know how to reach the required form, as I am having particular trouble altering $\frac{d}{dr}$ into $\frac{d}{dp}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dr} = \frac{dp}{dr}\frac{d}{dp}=k\frac{d}{dp}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now multiply this by $r$
\begin{eqnarray*}
r \frac{d}{dr} =p\frac{d}{dp}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply the original equation by $r$ & you done.

Comment: Chain rule & $p=kr$.

Comment: Is there any intuitive reason why we made this substitution (besides the fact that it worked)?

Comment: It neatens the differential equation & the operator $p\frac{d}{dp}$ will make it easier to obtain a power series solution.